# Prob. 5, Sec. 29, in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: Extension of a homeomorphism of locally compact Hausdorff spaces to their one-point compactifications

Tags: general-topology, continuity, compactness, solution-verification

Here is Prob. 5, Sec. 29, in the book *Topology* by James R. Munkres, 2nd edition:

> If $f \colon X_1 \rightarrow X_2$ is a homeomorphism of locally compact Hausdorff spaces, show $f$ extends to a homeomorphism of their one-point compactifications.

My Attempt:

Here is Theorem 29.1 in Munkres.

> Let $X$ be a [topological] space. Then $X$ is locally compact Hausdorff if and only if there exists a [topological] space $Y$ satisfying the following conditions:

> (1) $X$ is a subspace of $Y$.

> (2) The set $Y - X$ consists of a single point.

> (3) $Y$ is a compact Hausdorff space.

> If $Y$ and $Y^\prime$ are two spaces satisfying these conditions, then there is a homeomorphism of $Y$ with $Y^\prime$ that equals the identity map on $X$.

The proof of Theorem 29.1 shows that the collection of the open sets of $Y$ consists of (1) all the open sets $U$ of $X$, and (2) all sets of the form $Y - C$ where $C$ is a compact subspace of $X$.

Following the proof of this theorem, Munkres states:

> If $X$ should happen to be compact, then the space $Y$ of the preceding theorem is not very interesting, for it is obtained from $X$ by adjoining a single isolated point. However, if $X$ is not compact, then the point of $Y - X$ is a limit point of $X$, so that $\overline{X} = Y$.

After that, Munkres gives this definition.

> If $Y$ is a compact Hausdorff space and $X$ is a proper subspace of $Y$ whose closure equals $Y$, then $Y$ is said to be a *compactification* of $X$. If $Y - X$ equals a single point, then $Y$ is called the *one-point compactification* of $X$.

Finally, Munkres states the following.

> We have shown that $X$ has a one-point compactification $Y$ if and only if $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space that is not itself compact. We speak of $Y$ as "the" one-point compactification because $Y$ is uniquely determined up to a homeomorphism.

Now here is my attempt at Prob. 5, Sec. 29, in Munkres.

> As $f \colon X_1 \rightarrow X_2$ is a homeomorphism of topological space $X_1$ with topological space $X_2$, so

> (1) the map $f$ is a *bijective* mapping of $X_1$ onto $X_2$,

> (2) the image set $f\left(U_1 \right)$ is an open set in $X_2$ whenever $U_1 \subset X_1$ and $U_1$ is an open set in $X_1$, and

> (3) the inverse image $f^{-1}\left( U_2 \right)$ is an open set in $X_1$ whenever $U_2 \subset X_2$ and $U_2$ is an open set in $X_2$.

> Let $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ be the one-point compactifications, respectively, of $X_1$ and $X_2$.

> For each $r = 1, 2$, the open sets of $Y_r$ are as follows: (1) all sets $U_r$ that are open in $X_r$, and (2) all sets of the form $Y_r - C_r$ where $C_r$ is a compact subspace of $X_r$.

> For each $r = 1, 2$, let $p_r$ be the single point of $Y_r - X_r$.

> Now let $\tilde{f} \colon Y_1 \rightarrow Y_2$ be the mapping defined as
> $$
> \tilde{f}(y) \colon= 
> \begin{cases} 
> f(y) \ & \mbox{ if } \ y \in X, \\
> p_2 \ & \mbox{ if } \ y = p_1. 
> \end{cases} \tag{Definition A}
> $$

> We note that, as the mapping $f \colon X_1 \rightarrow X_2$ is bijective, so also is the mapping $\tilde{f} \colon Y_1 \rightarrow Y_2$.

> Now let $V_1$ be any open set in $Y_1$. We show that $\tilde{f}\left( V_1 \right)$ is an open set in $Y_2$. The following two cases arise.

> Case 1. If $V_1$ is an open set in $X_1$, then we find that
> $$ \tilde{f}\left( V_1 \right) = f\left( V_1 \right), $$
> which is an open set in $X_2$ and hence this set is also open in $Y_2$.

> Case 2. If $V_1 = Y_1 - C_1$ for some compact subspace $C_1$ of $X_1$, then we have
> $$ \tilde{f} \left( V_1 \right) = \tilde{f} \left( Y_1 - C_1 \right)  = \tilde{f} \left( Y_1 \right) - \tilde{f} \left( C_1 \right) = Y_2 - f \left( C_1 \right), \tag{1} $$
> because $\tilde{f}$ is bijective and also because $C_1 \subset X_1$.

> Now as $C_1$ is a compact subspace of $X_1$ and the map $f \colon X_1 \rightarrow X_2$ is continuous, so the image set $f \left( C_1 \right)$ is a compact subspace of $X_2$. Therefore $Y_2 - f \left( C_1 \right)$ is an open set of $Y_2$. That is, $\tilde{f} \left( V_1 \right)$ is open in $Y_2$, by (1) above.

> Alternatively, as $f \left( C_1 \right)$ is a compact subspace of $X_2$ and as $X_2$ is a subspace of $Y_2$, so $f \left( C_1 \right)$ is a compact subspace of $Y_2$ also.

> And, as $Y_2$ is a Hausdorff space and as $f \left( C_1 \right)$ is a compact subspace of $Y_2$, so $f \left( C_1 \right)$ is closed in $Y_2$. Therefore the set
> $Y_2 - f \left( C_1 \right)$ is open in $Y_2$; that is, $\tilde{f} \left( V_1 \right)$ is open in $Y_2$. [Refer to (1) above.]

> Thus we have shown that, for any open set $V_1$ in $Y_1$, the image set $\tilde{f}\left( V_1 \right)$ is also open in $Y_2$. Therefore $\tilde{f}$ is an *open* map.

> Using a symmetric argument to show that the inverse mapping $\tilde{g} \colon Y_2 \rightarrow Y_1$ of $\tilde{f}$ is also open, we can conclude that the map $\tilde{f}$ is continuous.

> Hence $\tilde{f} \colon Y_1 \rightarrow Y_2$ is a bijective continuous mapping that is also open. Hence $\tilde{f}$ is a homeomorphism.

> Finally, from (Definition A) it is evident that the homeomorphism $\tilde{f} \colon Y_1 \rightarrow Y_2$ is an extension of the homeomorphism $f \colon X_1 \rightarrow X_2$.

Is this proof correct? If so, is it rigorous enough? Or, is there something lacking in my reasoning? Is there any detail that I have omitted?

Comment: Looks pretty good!

Comment: It’s fine. If anything it’s a little more detailed than is really necessary, though that does depend on the intended audience (and is in case far better than being insufficiently detailed!).